# Comparison of individual Array Values

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Whenever I try to compare array values, I get the error- "TypeError: Cannot read property "0" from undefined."
How to compare individual array values?

```
var source=scanner.getRange(6, 1, 140).getValues();
var osc=SpreadsheetApp.openById("some id").getSheetByName("Sheet1").getRange(2, 1,50).getValues();
for( var i=0;i<=140;i++){
for(var j=0;j<=50;j++){

  if(source[i][0]==osc[j][0]){
  scanner.getRange(i+6, 5).setValue("abc");
  }}
```

Comment: Even if both the array size are kept same, Same error is displayed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Issue:

When you get 140 rows of data, There are 140 elements in the outer array(Index from 0 to 139). But your for-loop loops through 141 rows, from 0 to 140. `source[140]` will be undefined. And `undefined` doesn't have a `[0]` property.

#### Solution:

Use proper index

#### Code snippet:

```
for(var i=0;i<=139;i++){
  for(var j=0;j<50;j++){//Note missing `=`
```

#### To Read:

- [Arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array)
- [Best Practices](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/best-practices#use_batch_operations)